# WPF animate StrokeDashArray

Tags: wpf, animation

I'm trying to create an animation in WPF but I'm quite confused about where to place everything..
I need a circle that grows, like drawing himself.

To do so I have a nicely designed circle (one stroked circle with a blured stroked clircle below)
Then I have another circle with StrokeDashArray. I plan to use this circle as a opacityMask for the first ones and animate the StrokeDashArray to reveal the circ.

Ive been playing around and I can modify the StrokeDashArray from [0, 100] to [50 100] and I get a growing line covering the circle (I really don't inderstand where the 0 100 and the 50 100 came from.. just tried until it looks nice.

So now my problem is where to distribute the stuff.

my code so far looks like:

```
<UserControl bla bla bla bla>
    <!-- The mask that should be animated -- >
    <Ellipse Name="Mask" Stroke="White"StrokeThickness="13" StrokeDashArray="10 100"/>
    <!-- StrokeDashArray should be animated from "0 100" to "50 100"  -->

    <!-- The Blurry shadow of the line -->
    <Ellipse Name="blurry" Stroke="#FF7CA2CE" StrokeThickness="5">
        <Ellipse.Effect>
            <BlurEffect/>
        </Ellipse.Effect>
        <Ellipse.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Mask}"/>
        </Ellipse.OpacityMask>
    </Ellipse>

    <!-- The line itself -->
    <Ellipse Name="core" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="1">
        <Ellipse.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=Mask}"/>
        </Ellipse.OpacityMask>
    </Ellipse>
</UserControl>
```

So now I need to perform the animation over the first element in the StrokeDashArray and start it from code behind (C#)
I can also let the animation soemewhere as a resource and start it from the code, or perform the whole animation in the code, I dont care, but please be specific about where to add the code for it.. I feel lost.

I also tried to add teh blurry and core lines to one grid and then apply the VisualBrush to it (so I apply it only one time, not two) but the effect is uglier since the blurry line is cut and is not softly ending like we want it to be hehehe

Sooo, Any help ?!?!?!?!?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit of a tricky one as `StrokeDashArray` is a `DoubleCollection` so you cant really animate the values inside and have it reflect in the UI.

One option would be to animate a `double` property and create a new `DoubleCollection` that is bound to the `StrokeDashArray`.

Here is a working example:

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication21.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="211.75" Width="213" Name="UI">

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}">

        <Ellipse x:Name="lo" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="13" StrokeDashArray="{Binding StrokeArray}" />

        <Ellipse Name="blurry" Stroke="#FF7CA2CE" StrokeThickness="5">
            <Ellipse.Effect>
                <BlurEffect/>
            </Ellipse.Effect>
            <Ellipse.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=lo}"/>
            </Ellipse.OpacityMask>
        </Ellipse>

        <!-- The line itself -->
        <Ellipse Name="core" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="1">
            <Ellipse.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=lo}"/>
            </Ellipse.OpacityMask>
        </Ellipse>

        <Button Content="Start" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="49" Margin="29,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="150" Click="Button_Click_1"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication21
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public double StrokeValue
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(StrokeValueProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StrokeValueProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeValueProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("StrokeValue", typeof(double), typeof(MainWindow)
            , new PropertyMetadata(0.0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnStrokeValueChanged)));

        private static void OnStrokeValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            (d as MainWindow).StrokeArray = new DoubleCollection { (double)e.NewValue, 100 };
        }


        public DoubleCollection StrokeArray
        {
            get { return (DoubleCollection)GetValue(StrokeArrayProperty); }
            set { SetValue(StrokeArrayProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeArrayProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("StrokeArray", typeof(DoubleCollection), typeof(MainWindow)
            , new PropertyMetadata(new DoubleCollection { 0, 100 }));


    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var storyboard = new Storyboard();
        var animation = new DoubleAnimation(0,50,new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)));
        storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, this);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation,new PropertyPath( MainWindow.StrokeValueProperty));
        storyboard.Begin();
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: WOW, simply WOW... It could took me years to discover it all by myself.. Actually there are parts I really don't get how they work in there .. but it works. For sure.

Comment: Just one thing, as I commented in my question, I need to start/control the animation from code behind (C#) I need to set the duration and start it from there.

Is it easy to do ?

Comment: I have updated the answer/example to run the animation from code  :)

Comment: I managed to do it setting the storyboard as a resource and then calling it like that:    
    Storyboard sb =  (Storyboard)FindResource("unfoldSB");
    sbd.Begin(this);

Is any approach better than the other ??

Comment: I really get lost on how it works .. can you gimme some details on how it works ?? May be with a simpler example, let say animating just a single double like opacity or width

Thanks Man!  I really find no nice manual/tutorial on the topic :(

Comment: There is a very good animation tutorial here, it shows Xaml and code behind examples, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx

Answer (score 11):

Actually, you can animate the StrokeDashOffset instead of trying to animate the StrokeDashArray.

```
<Rectangle
   Width="70"
   Height="70"
   StrokeDashArray="2 0 0 2"
   StrokeThickness="2"
   Stroke="Black"
   Opacity="1"
   Fill="Transparent">
   <Rectangle.Triggers> 
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded"> 
                <BeginStoryboard> 
                    <Storyboard> 
                        <DoubleAnimation 
                           To="20" 
                           Duration="0:0:5" 
                           RepeatBehavior="Forever" 
                           By="2" 
                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeDashOffset" /> 
                    </Storyboard> 
                </BeginStoryboard> 
            </EventTrigger> 
        </Rectangle.Triggers> 
   </Rectangle>
```

Comment: I added `StrokeDashArray="4,2" ` and   `Storyboard.TargetName="Rectangle1" ` (Rectangle1 is the name of the Frameworkelement) then it works smooth as best solution because it is in XAML only.

Answer (score 0):

Animations are much easier to design and adjust inside Expression Blend.

Depending on the edition of Visual Studio that you have, it may or may not come with it, or might have to be obtained separately.

Visual Studio 2012 comes with Expression Blend in the box (but you need to get the Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 for WPF support), otherwise you can get Expression Blend 4 separately, or as part of Expression Studio.

Then depending on your animation requirements:

- you can design a Storyboard which you can then begin from code behind, or from an attached behaviour action (ControlStoryboardAction)
- or you can use a VisualStateManager and in Blend in the States panel, define a set of states in a state group, and then tell the VisualStateManager which "state" you want to be set....you will get an animation between the states (if you have set the right values)....use VisualStateManager.GoToState(), or the attached behavior GotoToStateAction to change the state.

Once you have your animation designed, you can if you wish turn it into code-behind (by hand) to build and operate that animation, but generally you don't do that except for special cases.

(there was a tool that could do the conversion for you to some extent, but doesn't seem to be available ... http://www.xamlt.com/)

---

Some links to get you started:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/expression/cc197141.aspx
- http://www.kirupa.com/blend_wpf/index.htm
- http://www.blendinsider.com/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/expression/

Comment: IT is the first tiem I heard about that all and everything sounds new for .. do you know any good step by step tutorial / manual for this kind of things? The whole thing sounds pretty useful and interesting : )